# Adding Text To UIImage...Wrong spot

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage, uigraphicscontext

I'm trying to draw text to a `UIImage`. This method below works, but the text is off. I have the `*l` label in the center of the frame. After `self.image = [self drawText]`, the text is in the top left corner of the image.

```
-(UIImage*) drawText{
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(_creatorImageView.image.size, false, _creatorImageView.image.scale);
    [_creatorImageView.image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0,0,_creatorImageView.image.size.width, _creatorImageView.image.size.height)];

    NSLog(@"Caption ARRY: %@", _creatorImageView.captionArray);
    for (UILabel *l in _creatorImageView.captionArray){
        NSLog(@"%f   %f", l.frame.origin.x, l.frame.origin.y);
        CGRect rect = CGRectMake(l.frame.origin.x, l.frame.origin.y, _creatorImageView.image.size.width, _creatorImageView.image.size.height);
        [l.textColor set];
        CGFloat radians = atan2f(l.transform.b, l.transform.a);
        CGFloat degrees = radians * (180 / M_PI);

       //CGContextConcatCTM(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), CGAffineTransformMakeScale(l.transform.tx, l.transform.ty));
       //CGContextConcatCTM(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(),    CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(degrees));

        //NSMutableParagraphStyle *paragraphStyle = [NSMutableParagraphStyle new];
        //[paragraphStyle setLineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];
        //[paragraphStyle setAlignment:NSTextAlignmentCenter];

        NSDictionary *attributes = @{ NSFontAttributeName: l.font,
                                  NSForegroundColorAttributeName: l.textColor,
                                  NSBackgroundColorAttributeName: l.backgroundColor};
                                  //NSParagraphStyleAttributeName:paragraphStyle};

        [l.text drawInRect:rect withAttributes:attributes];
        NSLog(@"TEXT: %@", l.text);

    }
    UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return newImage;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using the code

```
[l.text drawInRect:rect withAttributes:attributes];
```

To draw your text. The `rect` rectangle you specify controls where the text is drawn, in the coordinates of your context (where 0,0 is the upper-left of your context.)

If you want your text centered in your context, calculate the center if your context, and adjust the origin of your rect to center the text there.

I'll leave you to work out the math. It would only be a few lines of code.

Comment: The `rect.x = 119.5` and `rect.y = 340.5`. It's the label coordinates. Thats why I'm confused as to why it's in the top left corner. @Duncan C